# NSFetchedResultsController and TableViews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use Core Data with a NSFetchedResultsController.

The data model is devided into "tree levels".

Parent -> (Many) Children -> (Many) Grandchildren

In a table view I would like to show all the Childs of the parent as sections and the GrandChildrens as cells. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Data Model:

```
Parent:
name NSString*
Id NSNumber*
child NSSet* (set of childs)

Child:
name NSString*
childId NSNumber*
parent Parent*
childrensChilds NSSet* (set of childrensChilds)

ChildrensChild:
name NSString*
ChildrensChildId NSNumber*
parentChild *Child
```

FetchRequest:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"ChildId" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent.parentId = %@", self.parentId];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Childrens"];
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

[fetchRequest release];
[theFetchedResultsController release];
```

Then i would like to create section headers with Child names and the cells to be named after childrenschild.

Comment: give us some code and the data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a fetched results controller (FRC) with a tableview, you set the fetch entity to the entity that will populate the rows. After all, sections are optional but rows are always required.

The first thing you need to do is to set reciprocal relationships in your data model like so:

```
Parent<-->>Child<-->>GrandChild
```

... this allows you to transverse the object starting with any entity e.g. if you have a Grandchild object, you use the keypath 'parentChild.parent' (or whatever you call the relationships) to reach the related `Parent` object by transversing the `Child` object.

To configure the tableview as you wish, you would set the fetch entity to `GrandChild`, the predicate to something like `parentChild.parent.id=%@` and then set the FRC `sectionNameKeyPath` to `parentChild.name`.

However, you probably want to rethink your entire design. A simpler data model for a tree structure would be:

```
Person{
  name:string
  id:number
  parent<<-->Person.children
  children<-->>Person.parent
}
```

With grandchild being a child two traverses down and grandparent being a parent two traverses up. Once you had any particular `Person` object, then displaying in a tableview would be trivial. The section names would be a sorted array of the 'children' relationship and the rows would be sorted arrays of the each child's own children.

You would need to fiddle with fetches at all.